# How to update exactly one record and select updated row in a single db2 query

Tags: sql, db2

I want to write a query which updates only one row of a table then returns updated rows.

I can achieve getting returned rows using

```
select field from final table 
(update tablename set anotherfield = 'dd' where someanotherfield = 'bb')
```

kind of statement. But i cannot update just one row.

Also my program that calls this query is a multithreaded one and i dont want to deadlock any processes so, i found SKIP LOCKED DATA statement which is like readpast in t-sql query.

So what i am trying to do is, my program uses an db2 table like a stack, selects only one row each time, updates it so any other thread cannot access it but does not make them wait 
entire table, they just skip updated row and select next record from table. Is this operation possible in a single db2 query?

I have written this query so far, and it cannot be processed

```
select COLUMN3 FROM FINAL TABLE
   ( 
      update MYTABLE 
      set    COLUMN1 = 'R'
      where  COLUMN1 = ''
          order by COLUMN2 
          FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY 
          SKIP LOCKED DATA 
   )
```

Any help would be appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: #winces# SQL is _defined_ to work best in **sets**, which means that it works best when it tries to update as many rows as possible.  What are you trying to accomplish here?  Note that if you _are_ trying to get some sort of messaging queue, the DB will actually be a bottle-neck for speed; you'd be better off with an actual 'message queue'-type program (many of which have resiliency features, on top of multithreading, too)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that COLUMN2 is a unique_id , you could do something like this:

```
select COLUMN3 FROM FINAL TABLE
( 
    update MYTABLE 
    set    COLUMN1 = 'R'
    where  COLUMN1 = ''
        AND COLUMN2 = ( SELECT COLUMN2 
                        FROM MYTABLE 
                        ORDER by COLUMN2 
                        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
    SKIP LOCKED DATA 

)
```

You were doing an order by inside your update and that doesn't work. You have to restrain that to only one result (likely using your primary key).

Comment: But i don't want to update every row, as the title says one want to update rows one by one.

Comment: That's true. I was looking at it the wrong way. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ok, it works. But i want to ask a question. Does it avoid deadlocks? Inner subquery which gets primary key makes committed reads, right? If i use that query in my multithreaded program, every thread would wait for another processes to get primary key element from the table, i think. Am i right? What is your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think you should write another question for that.